# What does IPDB stand for?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Working in the following environment:

Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Writing the code in Spyder. After running my code, I got the following prompt:

ipdb>

What does IPDB stand for?

Comment: Did you search for *'What does IPDB stand for in python?'* What did *google* tell you?

Comment: Google sent me to https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/. Nowhere on that site does it state Interactive Python DeBugger. I'm not a computer science major. Just trying to apply some of this to my field. Sorry if these questions are basic from your perspective.

Comment: I was just asking, because if you did add your research on the topic to question, that would surely help answers rightly pointed to your needs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive Python DeBugger

Use it to debug code via prompt.

[See documentation here.](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/)

[See demo video here.](https://youtu.be/8SNaW1nt6j0)

Comment: @PeterGoodall no problem, glad to help. Please up vote and select as answer :)

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true